# Increase quantity of food if user add to cart same food option Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I am build web for order food with laravel. If user add to cart same food in cart, quantity of food will increase. I created 3 model: OrderDetail, OrderOptionDetail, SubOption

Food model:

```
public function food_options(){
    return $this->hasMany(FoodOption::class);
}
public function order_detail(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
}
```

FoodOption model:

```
public function sub_options(){
    return $this->hasMany(SubOption::class);
}
```

OrderDetail model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'order_id','food_id', 'quantity'
];
public function order_option_detail(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderOptionDetail::class);
}
public function food(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Food::class);
}
```

OrderOptionDetail model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'order_detail_id', 'option_id','sub_option_id'
];
public function sub_option(){
    return $this->belongsTo(SubOption::class);
}
```

SubOption model:

```
 use Translatable;

public $translatedAttributes = [
    'name'
];
protected $fillable = [
    'food_option_id',
    'price'
];
```

In controller:

```
public function Order(Request $request){
        $orderDetail =  OrderDetail::where(['food_id' => $request->input('food'), 'order_id' => $order->id])->get();
        ...
        if(...){
            $orderDetail1->quantity += 1;
            $orderDetail1->save();
        }
    }
```

For example: Milk tea have FoodOption is Size and SubOption are S ($0), M($1), L ($1.5). In cart already  exists Milk tea Size S with quantity = 1. If user select Milk tea Size S and add to cart again. quantity will increase to 2. 
How to check this in controller. Thank everyone, so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this order exists then add it to quantity and save it, else create a new record, you also need a 'selected_option' input that shows the selected option :

```
        $orderDetail =  OrderDetail::where(['food_id' => $request->input('food'), 
        'order_id' => $order->id])->first();
        $check = $orderDetail->sub_option->where("food_option_id",$request->input('selected_option'));
    ...
    if($check->exists()){
        //$orderDetail =  OrderDetail::where(['food_id' => $request->input('food'), 
        //'order_id' => $order->id])->first();
        $orderDetail1->quantity += 1;
        $orderDetail1->save();
    }else{
        $orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
        ......
    }
```

Comment: but I want add order detail with same food and difference food option

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to check the selected option too, after that you add to quantity if you had a row, else create a new row. use commented code if this doesn't work.